# Android org.json issues with converting Map to JSON

Tags: android, json

I have some code to create a specific JSON result in Java (for Android):

```
Map<String, Object> jsonDict = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> dict = new HashMap<String, Object>();
dict.put(_operator, _value);
System.out.println("Dict is: " + new JSONObject(dict).toString());

jsonDict.put(_field, dict);
System.out.println("jsonDict is: " + new JSONObject(jsonDict).toString());
```

When I print out the results of each step is get:

```
Dict is: {"$eq":"asdf"} // <-- this line is correct
```

And the final result:

```
Filter 1 is: {"testing":"{eq=asdf}"}  // <-- this line is INCORRECT
```

The result I should get is:

```
{"testing":{"eq":"asdf"}}
```

When I put a `Map` inside the `Object` part of `Map` it switches it to a `String` and adds an = sign. Why does it do this and what can be done about it?

Note: "eq", "asdf", and "testing" are inputs given to my function.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
json.put("testing",new JSONObject(dict).toString())
```

**output:**

```
{"testing":{"eq":"asdf"}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
new JSONObject(gson.toJson(jsonDict));
```

**Output:**

```
{"testing":{"eq":"asdf"}}
```